# Using Wordpress Theme customizer or not?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-admin

I’m trying to create my own theme for a multisite WP and I stumble upon the following issue regarding the customization of the theme (via the admin).

## Overview

- I own three websites on the same multisite,
- I want to use the one theme for my three websites,
- I want my user to be able to customized said theme (per domain) as they see fit,
- Those options should be build-in in the theme.

There will be enough options for my websites to look entirely differents.

---

## Use case

In the admin I want my user to be able to do lots of things:

### 1 | Classical actions

- Change logos (regular and retina)
- Change favicon

### 2 | Components

In the design, we’ll have multiple versions of one components.
Meaning that I’m giving a choice to my user, such as:

> Do you want to display header *option 1, option 2 or option 3* ?
>
> Would you want this CTA to look like *option 1, option 2, or option 3* ?

You get the gist of it and this will also be applied to footers, shortcodes, etc.

### Styling & Colors

- Theme style: fullwidth version of the theme, centered...
- Header, Body and footer's colors (background, text, links…)
- etc.

---

I wanted to clarify the context before asking my question, I hope it’s clear for you.

## The question

Is it better to use **Wordpress Theme Customizer** OR to **create my own custom theme section in the admin** ?

And most importantly, **why** ?

I found out few articles about this matter and my understanding of the **Customizer**, is that it is convenient because:

- Options are all in one place
- Live preview
- Documentation

But I also saw a lot of **premium themes with custom section**, which seems more user-friendly, there’s more space for the interface, tabs...

---

Can you give me your take on this ? I don't want to start my developpement without any clue.
If you have articles on this subject I would be grateful !

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (like you said in the Use Case) you want your users to change logos and favicons, while also changing header, body and footer's colors. I would advise you to create your own custom theme section in the admin. It is more convenient and you have the freedom to give the user the choices you desire.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Do you have any article on how to do that ? Or should I just refer to the Codex ?

Comment: You can refer to the Codex for that. I believe this may be the one: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API